# "first electron affinities go from gaseous atoms to gaseous singly charged negative ions"

Tags: grammaticality

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/energetics/lattice.html):

> The -349 is the first electron affinity of chlorine. Remember that first electron affinities go from gaseous atoms to gaseous singly charged negative ions.

Is the second sentence well-formed? It looks illogical. "First electron affinities" here means "the amounts of energy evolved or expended when gaseous atoms turn into gaseous singly charged negative ions (by acquiring an  electron)".

Is it okay to abridge the sentence in this way?

There is another sentence formed similarly to the first one:

> The +496 is the first ionisation energy of sodium. Remember that first ionisation energies go from gaseous atoms to gaseous singly charged positive ions.

Comment: What part concerns you? I don't see an obvious problem (beyond the technical jargon anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Given the equation for [electron affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity)

> X + e− → X− + energy

the "energy" portion is the "first electron affinity" and one can see it "goes"(comes) from the changing of the charge neutral X(gas) to the negatively charged ion and thrown off energy (first electron affinity), having been part of the left-hand side of the equation.

Comment: Energy is *released* when an electron is added to the atom, it does not go from a gaseous atom to an anion.